# CVS file location is valid in Perl?

Tags: perl, cvs

Is there any way to find out that partiualr file exists or not in CVS? I don't want to check out the file, just want to see that file exists or not through Perl.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cvs status` command to check. Either

1. call that directly via a system call

   ```
   my @output = `cvs status $filename`;
   ```

   you can either heuristically grep the resulting text for `",v"` string (that always is the suffix for CVS repository file), or actually parse the output looking for "Repository revision:" line

   ```
      MISSING: Repository revision: No revision control file
      PRESENT: Repository revision: 10.41   /u1/cvs/dev/myscript.pl,v
   ```
2. or use  `Cvs` module:

   ```
   use Cvs; 
   my $cvs = new Cvs("/u1/cvs", cvsroot => $ENV{CVSROOT}, password =>"*****") 
       or die $Cvs::ERROR; 
   my $status = $cvs->status("CVS_file"); 
   print $status->status() . "\n";

   ====> Needs Checkout

   my $status = $cvs->status("bogus_file"); 
   print $status->status() . "\n";

   ====> Unknown
   ```

Comment: @Imran - Not quite. In my tests, a file that doesn't exist has "Status: Unknown" and the one that does has "Status: Needs Checkout". This could be because I already have the directory checked out, though

Comment: I am getting following error message when file is not checked oot "cvs [status aborted]: cannot find "My file": No such file or directory"

Comment: @DVK- I am able to see Unknown status if any other file from that particular directory is checked out, if nothing is checked out then "No such file or directory" displayed.